# Java - Why am I forced to cast a reference constructor into a Supplier, otherwise Java claims the method is ambigous?

Tags: java, methods, overloading, overload-resolution, functional-interface

I have the following defined interface which is intended to be implemented by all the implementations of a 3d vector:

```
public interface IVector3<T extends Number> extends IVector<T> {
    // Other stuff

    public static <T extends Number, V extends IVector3<T>> V cross(V target, IVector3<?> vector0, IVector3<?> vector1) {
        // Implementation
    }

    public static <T extends Number, V extends IVector3<T>> V cross(Supplier<V> factory, IVector3<?> vector0, IVector3<?> vector1) {
        return cross(factory.get(), vector0, vector1);
    }
}
```

I've also defined the follow implementation of the interface:

```
public class Vector3f extends Vectorf implements IVector3<Float> {
    // Other stuff

    public static Vector3f cross(IVector3<?> vector0, IVector3<?> vector1) {

        // The annoying required cast
        return IVector3.cross((Supplier<Vector3f>) Vector3f::new, vector0, vector1);
    }
}
```

So, why does java requires me to make that cast of the reference constructor otherwise it claims the call to the method to be ambiguous?

Shouldn't the bounded type parameter solve the ambiguity?

And finally, is there any solution to avoid having to cast the reference constructor without changing the bounded type parameters?

**Note**: No other class/interface in the hierarchy defines a method (static or not) named "cross".

**Note 2**: I'm using Java 12.

Comment: By the way, is there any reason you're using `IVector3<?>` and not `IVector3<? extends V>` or `IVector3<V>`?

Comment: @user Yes, I want to be able to apply the cross product between vectors that hold elements of any type of number (aka ```Integer```, ```Double```, ```Float```, ...).

Comment: It works just fine for me on repl.it. Are you sure there isn't anything else there?

Comment: @user Did you remove the cast ```(Supplier<Vector3f>)```? Because I just tested it, and it didn't work. [repl.it link](https://repl.it/repls/DarkkhakiBuoyantLint#Main.java)

Comment: My bad, I typed it in myself and replaced `V` with `IVector3` instead of directly copying it. I guess type erasure makes the first cross method take in an `Object`? This seems a bit like a bug though. Doing `IVector3.<Vector3f>cross` was the only thing that worked apart from the cast

Comment: @user Yeah, I really can't understand why it doensn't work without the cast. I just tested it with with the return types: ```Object```, ```<T extends Number> IVector3<T>``` and ```<T> T``` and they all work without the cast, once I make ```T``` extend ```IVector3``` it stops working without the cast.

Answer (score 1):

Primarily since it's unable to infer the type via the method reference or even lambda. If only you would let it know the type context with which you are invoking the `cross` method, it shall work. For example this -

```
return IVector3.<Float, Vector3f>cross(Vector3f::new, vector0, vector1);
```

Comment: For some reason I didn't remember to do that over the cast since I prefer that solution. However, I still don't quite understand why it can't infer the type, but I completely changed the structure of the code so it doesn't really matter that much anymore. Thanks anyways!